# Unable to install Node.js on Azure VM using CustomScriptForLinux

Tags: azure, azure-vm-templates

I am trying to create a Linux VM (CentOS 7) on Azure using Azure CLI and a template. I want the VM to be spun up with Node.js installed. In order to achieve this I used a CustomScriptForLinux block as below in the template.json.

```
{
  "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/<sub-id>/resourceGroups/testing/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/smartforecastingui/extensions/CustomScriptForLinux'.",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "name": "testin/install",
  "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
  "location": "eastus2",
  "tags": {
    "applicationname": "TestingApp"
  },
  "scale": null,
  "properties": {
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
      "fileUris": [
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodesource/distributions/master/rpm/setup_10.x"
      ]
    },
    "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
    "type": "['CustomScriptForLinux']",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
    "protectedSettings": {
      "commandToExecute": "bash setup_10.x && yum upgrade && yum install -y gcc-c++ make nodejs yarn"
    }
  },
}
```

When I try to create a VM with the command

```
az group deployment create --resource-group testing --template-file template.json --parameters parameters.json
```

It fails with the error :

```
Failed to download external file with uri: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodesource/distributions/master/rpm/setup_10.x
with error 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2815: ordinal not in range(128)\n\".
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: this kinda says your file encoding is bad. remove all the weird characters in the file (at position 2815). i think its those weird dashes: `—`

Comment: curl-ing the file and running the same comands works after the VM is created.

Comment: thats great, why dont you do that then? :)

Comment: trying to make the whole deployment automated for automatic scaling. so want to install the script as part of the VM creation.

Comment: jagzviruz you aren't executing the command the same way from the template as you would if you logged in to your VM and executed the code. So as was already suggested "remove all the weird characters in the file" The error isn't lying to you.

Comment: I don't own the file, its just a file shared by nodesource to install node.js on CentOS. When I use it from within a created VM, I execute the command as 
    `curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -`
and then I proceed to 
    `yum upgrade && yum install -y gcc-c++ make nodejs yarn`

Comment: cool. keep doing it by hand then